How do I enable client-side blocking of machine-generated answer box in Confluence search page?
My company uses the managed version of Atlassian Confluence. Recently, when I use the internal search, sometimes a box titled "Overview" appears over the search results, like so:

The box is lazy-loaded on the client side in a div with id="ai-answer-result-section", after the search results are.
How do I disable this box on the client side, as a user? Ideally I want not just to hide it visually with a CSS trick, but also to avoid producing the request which generates its content. I've tried uMatrix but unfortunately it's not feasible to block the entire API endpoint /gateway/api/gasv3/api/v1/batch. It may be ok to block requests which contain something like actionSubject: "aiAnswerExpand" in the payload:


Using one of the various CSS customisation extensions to apply a display: none to the box ID or parent items classes doesn't seem to work, perhaps because of the lazy loading.
